# Aurora: High Availability Option

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

What is the best way to have redundancy for `RDS Aurora` instance. Should we have two instance, one in each `AZ` like illustrated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html) OR create the read replica as illustrated [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erEBSsEXGBU)
Even though `Aurora` automatically replicates across three `AZs` do we still need the `Multi AZ` for the instance.
Would highly appreciate any inputs on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends what you're trying to achieve. Multi-AZ is for redundancy and having a hot standby, read replicas are to increase scale typically by offloading read traffic.

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976527/why-does-aws-rds-aurora-have-the-option-of-multi-az-deployment-when-it-does-re) to see why Aurora has a multi-az option. In short, Aurora keeps your data across three AZs but has one database instance. Setting up Multi-AZ for Aurora gives you very fast recovery from problems.